# Python object instantiation from within another object - is it a memory leak?

Tags: python, object, memory-leaks

Consider the following small Python GUI program, where the user can click a button over and over to cycle between window 1 and window 2:

```
import tkinter

class Window1:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # Initialize a new GUI window
        self.parent = parent
        self.window = tkinter.Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.window.title('Window 1')

        # Make a button to launch Window 2
        launch_window_2_button = tkinter.Button(self.window, text='Launch Window 2')
        launch_window_2_button.config(command=self.launch_window_2)
        launch_window_2_button.pack()

    def launch_window_2(self):
        self.window.destroy()
        Window2(self.parent)


class Window2:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # Initialize a new GUI window
        self.parent = parent
        self.window = tkinter.Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.window.title('Window 2')

        # Make a button to launch Window 1
        launch_window_1_button = tkinter.Button(self.window, text='Launch Window 1')
        launch_window_1_button.config(command=self.launch_window_1)
        launch_window_1_button.pack()

    def launch_window_1(self):
        self.window.destroy()
        Window1(self.parent)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Initialize and hide the root GUI
    # (each class will spawn a new window that is a child of the root GUI)
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    Window1(root) # Start by spawning Window 1
    root.mainloop()
```

**Question 1:** Since each new class is being instantiated from within another class, is this a memory leak?

**Question 2:** Is this the most correct and Pythonic way to code this application?

**Question 3:** Assuming that the answer to question 1 is no, what if I changed `Window1(self.parent)` to `self.something = Window1(self.parent)`. Now that there is a reference, is it a memory leak now?

Comment: A memory leak is when you don't free memory when it is no longer being used. For example, if you have a program that reads lines from a file, and you allocate new memory for each line but never free one line's memory before you read the next line, this is a memory leak.  There is no way to free that memory because you no longer have a reference to it, so the amount of memory used by your program will grow and grow. Python manages memory for you, and in that scenario the memory would be released automatically. How or where an object is instantiated has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question 1: Since each new class is being instantiated from within another class, is this a memory leak?

No. And I think you are confusing between a few things memory leak and object references not being used. @kindall explains it beautifully in his comment under your question.

The best way to understand what is going is to know that the `tkinter.TopLevel(..)` constructor is [side-effects based.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect) It will hold the reference to your window within the root object, so that it knows how to deal with various windows. *And so is the constructor of your class.* Once it creates a `self.window` and somehow has `root` have reference to it, its job is done. The reference of this object is held too, although not explicitly (see answer to your Question 3 below).

---

> Question 2: Is this the most correct and Pythonic way to code this application?

The fact that references to the objects `Window1` and `Window2` objects are not used bugs me too. Other than that, I'd probably store away the references of the window elements(buttons, etc) also within the object -- They might not be of any immediate use, but they might be later on.

---

> Question 3: Assuming that the answer to question 1 is no, what if I
>   changed the following lines:
>
> Window1(self.parent)
>
> to:
>
> self.something = Window1(self.parent)
>
> Now that there is a reference, is it a memory leak now?

Think about the below line:

```
launch_window_2_button.config(command=self.launch_window_2)
```

In order for that line to work, tkinter has to store the reference of `self.launch_window2` (and thereby `self`) somewhere, so your `self.something` is not doing anything significant at all.. :)

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you show me a code snippet that addresses "The fact that references to the objects Window1 and Window2 objects are not used"? I don't quite understand. Why would I want a reference to those windows in the context of this program?

Comment: In the context of this program, you might not want the references to the Window object. I was only hinting at how much it bugs me to not have one. Personally, I do not like the idea of a deeply nested function storing the reference of an object. It *probably* hints at poor "ownership" of resources. But since this is a library, I dont think you can do much about it.. sadly